# How to start a download with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, download

I'm new to Javascript. I have to code a download script which makes users wait five seconds before the download starts. I want to use Javascript. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout) to trigger a function that will run `window.location = "http://yoururl.to/yourfile";`

Answer (score 1):

That would be something like this:

window.setTimeout(nameOfDownloadfunction,5000);